# Same name in typedef and using from a namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, language-lawyer, typedef, ambiguous

Sample code:

```
struct X { void f() {} };
typedef X A;

namespace N { 
    struct A { void g() {} };
};

using N::A;

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.f();
}
```

This code compiles correctly, and `A a;` creates an `X`, not a `N::A`.

What rule in the standard covers this behaviour? I was expecting an error that `A a;` would be ambiguous. If I name the first struct `A` instead of `X` and remove the typedef, then I do get such an error. (g++ 8.3)

Comment: Clang states that the reference to `A` is ambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

According to [[namespace.udecl]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.udecl#1) `using N::A` introduces the unqualified `A` into the declarative region in which the using declaration appears.

> ... the unqualified-id is declared in the declarative region in which the using-declaration appears as a synonym for each declaration introduced by the using-declarator.

So the ambiguity is covered jointly by [[namespace.udecl]/13](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.udecl#13)

> Since a using-declaration is a declaration, the restrictions on declarations of the same name in the same declarative region also apply to using-declarations.

and [[basic.scope.declarative]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.scope.declarative#4)

> Given a set of declarations in a single declarative region, each of
>   which specifies the same unqualified name,
>
> - they shall all refer to the same entity, or all refer to functions and function templates; or
> - exactly one declaration shall declare a class name or enumeration name that is not a typedef name and the other declarations shall all refer to the same variable, non-static data member, or enumerator, or all refer to functions and function templates; in this case the class name or enumeration name is hidden.

The `typedef` declaration and the using declaration in the OP don't fill either bullet, so the pair of declarations in the same declarative region is ill-formed.

Comment: `using N::A;` doesn't specify an unqualified name though, so I'm not sure how the second quote applies?  (Also no compiler reports an error for `using N::A;` although maybe that is a bug)

Comment: @M.M - `using N::A` adds the unqualified name `A` into the declarative region it appears in. But maybe it's the lookup that should turn up the issue. I'll double check.

Comment: Didn't find anything in name lookup. So I'm not sure if it should emit a diagnostic when the name is introduced or when it's lookup up, but I'm certain the two bullets above should make it ill-formed.